# How to show history of a specific user in svn?

Tags: svn

Now the history is mixed,how can I filter by user ?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  TortoiseSVN on Windows will let you do this...

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it using TortoiseSVN on Windows:

Right click your repository and you should have a menu like the following, in the TortoiseSVN submenu at the top you have "Show log" like this:

[image]

Clicking that will get you the log window where you can get all the information you want.

1. Click "Show All" at the bottom to get the entire log for the repository.
2. Click the Magnifying glass icon and select "Authors" in the dropdown.
3. Fill in your username and press enter.

[image]

For me this shows only my actions on that repository when I put in my username.